# Center justify dynamic images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed width container div in which I am loading fixed height images(the width is auto), dynamically-<del>using ajax</del>. I have made each image float to left. The problem is, if the new image doesn't fit into the present line it skips that line into the next, forming a negative space in the original line. So, I would like all my images to be aligned in the middle, like center-justify in MS office. How can I do this, jQuery solutions are also welcome.

[image]

---

ADD ON:

Okay, I am using [this file upload plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo). When I select multiple images to upload, these images are put into the container `div` (`.file-preview-thumbnails`) and they are kind of floated left, Now I would like them to be centered as shown in the above diagram. How can I do this?

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0uwLd8rj/

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?? Or provide a jsfiddle with your html and css codes

Comment: you can use [http://placehold.it/](http://placehold.it/) to simulate the image sizes when you want to provide a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o7bbhavj/ an image is an inline element, no need to float, give the container a text align center and it should behave as you describe.

Comment: @axel.michel you dont want to post this as an answere ? here is axel's [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7bbhavj/1/)

Comment: @Dwza it is fine like this - this is not a jQuery/ JavaScript or HTML Problem at all, and the CSS is just one single property.

Comment: I have updated the question with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center` centers the images in each line.

`padding: 5px` provides a little space between the images for a better look.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 700px;  
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  text-align: center;
}
#container img {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--2mI-K7Az--/bjtilnpurih2mbpxqaxz.jpg' />
  <img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qVdh0wel-Yo/mqdefault.jpg' />
  <img src='https://lh5.ggpht.com/KkTRxLuiXd_PXv-YePcJNXdvFFhCu9QxpCNEZraghdaaFjeExzQQTiodGYKXBev9IkI=w300' />
  <img src='http://www.ltwmag.com/images/_Dec_news_images/annoyingorange260.gif' />
  <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5f/Annoying_Orange_Kicthen_Carange_icon_175x175.png' />  
</div>
```